# Multiple replace of literals by digits

Tags: java

I need to replace multiple literals by digits in a string like "FF432423FA112". "A"=0, "B"=1 etc. I've tried to do it in a loop like but it didn't work. Tried also with char array

```
String test = "FF432423FA112";
String[] letters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    for (int i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
        newStr = test.replace(letters[i],i);
    }
```

Comment: newStr is a new string each time, so it will only be `test.replace(letters[n], n);` where n = letters.length -1.

Comment: Also, you probably need to convert `i` to a number? Can you explain *why* your loop doesn't work? Maybe it is one of the two things I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you forget to use `newStr.replace`, every time loop will generate the last `test.replace` copy character

```java
        String test = "FF432423FA112";
        String[] letters = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        String newStr = test;
        for (int i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
            newStr = newStr.replace(letters[i], i + "");
        }

        System.out.println(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If given string is "FF432423FA112" and the expected output is "5543242350112" considering to replace only alphabets and retain number as is, below code is an example.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "FF432423FA112";
        String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        int value = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<test.length(); i++) {
            char c = test.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                value = Character.getNumericValue(c);
            } else {
                value = letters.indexOf(c);
            }
            output.append(value);
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```